# CakePHP only localises part of the page

Tags: cakephp, localization

Locally everything is working. But when I create a container and push it to cloud parts of website don't get localized. So far have no idea why as there are no errors thrown.

What is the best way to figure this out?
I checked the po files and they look OK.

Comment: If you could add some hints maybe... like, which messages specifically? Do the affected messages live in separate translation files? Are all messages in a specific translation file affected, or only some of the messages? Have you checked your error logs? Have you tried clearing the cache? Have you checked that all the files are readable, and that the cache is writable?

Comment: it's all in one file and it looks like it translates to part of the file and then it stops. Yes, all files are readable and cache is writable. I see translation cache files written.

Comment: Ok so this is weird. I did some testing in my docker container and this is how you make the files to parse. I first thought that the problem is because they have `#m fuzzy` in header but that is not the case. So when I redeploy the container and if I browse the website it wil not work. Even if I remove the whole tmp folder it will not parse localization files. Here is the weird part. If I do `ls -la src\Locale` it will magically parse the files and localization will start to work. I thried running `chown -R www-data:www-data *` on fresh deployed container and it had no effect.

Comment: But as soon as I did `ls -la src\Locale` and removed cache folder the localization started to work on the website. So the `tmp` folder structure is not a problem because on a fresh container if I do `ls` on Locale folder it will work. How is this possible is beyond me, any ideas?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea...